# Reverse Linked-List Recursive

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I've traced through my code to reverse a linked-list using recursion, and I cannot find anything wrong with it, but I know it does not work. Can anyone please explain why?

```
Node reverseLL (Node head) {
  if(curr.next == null) {
    head = curr;
    return head;
  }

  Node curr = head.next;
  prev = head;
  head.next = prev;
  head = next;
  reverseLL(head.next);
}
```

Comment: How can you use `curr` before declaring it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working version of your code, added with some helping structures:

```
class LList {
    Node head;

    void reverse() {
        head = rev(head, head.next);
    }

    private Node rev(Node node, Node next) {
        if(next == null)    return node; //return the node as head, if it hasn't got a next pointer.
        if(node == this.head)   node.next = null; //set the pointer of current head to null.

        Node temp = next.next;
        next.next = node; //reverse the pointer of node and next.
        return rev(next, temp); //reverse pointer of next node and its next.
    }
}

class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
    public Node(int val, Node next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `reverseLL(head.next)` before the switching, to traverse down the list and start from the last node upwards. This requires some more changes though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible implementation.

First one with a pointer to the `head` (a class attribute) within your class

```
class Solution:
head: Optional[ListNode]
    
def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    node = head
    
    if node == None:
        return node
    
    if node.next == None:
        self.head = node
        return
    
    
    self.reverseList(node.next)
    q = node.next
    q.next = node
    node.next = None

    return self.head
```

Second solution, does not rely on a class attribute to conserve the `head` once you find it. It returns the pointer to the `head` through the recursive calls stack

```
def reverseList(head):
  # Empty list is always None
  if not head:
    return None

  # List of length 1 is already reversed
  if not head.next:
    return head


  next = head.next
  head.next = None
  rest = reverseList(next)
  next.next = head

  return rest
```